# How to link a button to another page in Android (Java)

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm using android studio and need help with adding a button that can take you to the next page of the app.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use Intents to go to another page in android studio

Add to your button an onClick function:

```
    android:onClick="startSecondActivity"
```

and then you have to add the function which should look like this:

```
    public void startSecondActivity(View view) {
    Intent intent = new intent (this, secondActivity.class);
    startActivity(Intent); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1.Add onClick event to Button.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Button xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/button_send"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_send"
    android:onClick="goNextPage" />
```

2.Within the Activity that hosts this layout, the following method handles the click event:

```
/** Called when the user touches the button */

public void goNextPage(View view) {
    startActivity(new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NextActivity.class));
}
```

> If you want to go Fragment, I will update my answer.